# Optimizing SDF filesize

Tags: c#, windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I recently started learning Linq and SQL. As a small project I'm writing a dictionary application for Windows Phone. The project is split into two Applications. One Application (that currently runs on my PC) generates a SDF file on my PC. The second App runs on my Windows Phone and searches the database. However I would like to optimize the data usage. The raw entries of the dictionary are written in a TXT file with a filesize of around 39MB. The file has the following layout

```
germanWord \tab englishWord \tab group
germanWord \tab englishWord \tab group
```

The file is parsed into a SDF database with the following tables.

Table *Word* with columns *_version (rowversion), Id (int IDENTITY), Word (nvarchar(250)), Language (int)*
This table contains every single word in the file. The language is a flag from my code that I used in case I want to add more languages later. A word-language pair is unique.

Table *Group* with columns *_version (rowversion), GroupId (int IDENTITY), Caption (nvarchar(250))*
This table contains the different groups. Every group is present one time.

Table *Entry* with columns *_version (rowversion), EntryId (int IDENTITY), WordOneId (int), WordTwoId(int), GroupId(int)*
This table links translations together. *WordOneId* and *WordTwoId* are foreign keys to a row in the *Word* Table, they contain the id of a row. *GroupId* defines the group the words belong to.

I chose this layout to reduce the data footprint. The raw textfile contains some german (or english) words multiple times. There are around 60 groups that repeat themselfes. Programatically I reduce the wordcount from around 1.800.000 to around 1.100.000. There are around 50 rows in the *Group* table. Despite the reduced number of words the SDF is around 80MB in filesize. That's more than twice the size of the the raw data. Another thing is that in order to speed up the searching of translation I plan to index the *Word* column of the *Word* table. By adding this index the file grows to over 130MB.

How can it be that the SDF with ~60% of the original data is twice as large?

Is there a way to optimize the filesize?

Answer (score 0):

The database file must contain all of the data from your raw file, in addition to row metadata -- it also will contain the strings based on the datatypes specified -- I believe your option here is `NVARCHAR` which uses two bytes per letter. Combining these considerations, it would not surprise me that a database file is over twice as large as a text file of the same data using the ISO-Latin-1 character set.